# What is the easiest way to win this endgame in a blitz game?

Tags: endgame, strategy

Say you're in a blitz game and you and your opponent both have 45 seconds left.

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "6k1/3p2pp/p7/1pPq4/1P6/P5RP/6PK/8 w - - 0 45"]
```

My question is how would would you go about winning this with black and what would you do with white to try to draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black's strategy is very straightforward. Push a5 to break up white's queen side pawns, win two of them leaving the d pawn as a passer and then queen it. There's not much white can do.

White should probably start with Rf3 to anchor the rook and cut off the black king from the center but it won't stop black's simple plan. It could look something like this:

```
[fen "6k1/3p2pp/p7/1pPq4/1P6/P5RP/6PK/8 w - - 0 45"]

1. Rf3 a5 2. bxa5 Qxc5 3. Kh1 Qc1+ 4. Kh2 Qc7+ 5. Kh1 Qxa5 6. Rd3 Qe1+ 7. Kh2 Qe5+ 8. Kh1 d5
```

Comment: Suppose black has no a-pawn. What would the next easiest win be?

Comment: @user35472: The same as *my* plan: Qe5 to win a few tempi, walk with the king to the queen side (c4 at least), sacrifice the Q against the rook and gobble up the pawns. If the white R rears its ugly head, fork him off. If you see such things at 45 seconds. But 45 seconds might be a bit slow. (Question spawned off!)